# How to access the web page without port range and index.html

Tags: http, web, networking, server

The address of my website is http://www.aboutsamyuen.com:8080/index.html

This is what I show on the first page: [image]

However, how can I access the page without port range and with http://www.aboutsamyuen.com

only, which means when I enter this link in browser and it will show Hello World.

I am using the aws service and this is my code in server.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer( function (request, response) {
  var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
  console.log("Trying to find '" + pathname.substr(1) + "'...");

  fs.readFile(pathname.substr(1), function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      response.write("ERROR: Cannot find '" + pathname.substr(1) + "'.");
      console.log("ERROR: Cannot find '" + pathname.substr(1) + "'.");
    } else {
      console.log("Found '" + pathname.substr(1) + "'.");
      response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      response.write(data.toString());
    }
    response.end();
  });
}).listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
```

Since I am not familiar with networking, how should I modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code:

```
if (pathname == '/') pathname = '/index.html';
```

after this line of code:

```
var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
```

& change `8080` to `80` in this line of code:

```
listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
```

Comment: Thanks, after following your instruction, I can use http://http://www.aboutsamyuen.com:8080 to access the page but if I change 8080 to 80 in listen(8080, '0.0.0.0'), there is an error and the code cannot be run.